# Reason for such shape of wave

Tags: waves, wavefunction, wave-particle-duality, wavelength

Why is the shape of wave as such? why are they curves up and down, why not straight lines like up and down squares.

Comment: Can you give an example of a wave you are interested in? Certainly square waves are allowed mathematically, but physically might be hard or impossible to create depending on what you are looking at.

Comment: i am intrested in waves created by sound, water etc

Comment: You can make (non-ideal)  square sound waves, so your question is still unclear.

Comment: like how can we make square sound waves and what are the factors which decide whether the shape is square or curved. this is basically what i am asking

Comment: Have you heard of [Fourier Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis)?

Comment: A loudspeaker whose diaphragm is made by electrical current to move back and forth between two positions, with very quick transitions in between those positions, will make an approximate “square” sound wave. You can make sound waves of any shape you want by varying the current driving the loudspeaker in the right way.

Answer (score 2):

As the commenters say, square waves are possible.  But in the real world the frequency characteristics of the transmitter and the medium will cause some distortion.

Any function of the form $f(x-ct)$ will satisfy the wave equation; including square waves, triangle waves, pulse trains, and single pulses.

However, it seems the most common waves are sinusoidal waves: sound waves, light waves,...

Re.

> what are the factors which decide whether the shape is square or
>   curved. this is basically what i am asking

*They are the frequency characteristics of the transmitter and the medium. For example, the original signal could be a square wave but after it has passed through the transmitter and the wave propagation medium it might have curved edges (due to rise times and fall times) and some ringing at the transition points (due to attenuation of the higher harmonics).*